# Checking if a set is definable in a given structure

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am trying to find out whether the integers divisible by certain numbers are definable in the structure of $\mathbb{Z}$.

but I really have no clue how to even begin, I've been sitting at my desk for such a long time now. :( I would really appreciate if anybody had an idea about this?

Thanks so much, Lin

Comment: I don't model theory, but are you trying to find out if an integer is divisible by $11$ based solely on its divisibility by $2$, $4$, and $7$?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure, but I don't think so. For instance, in a structure $(\mathbb{N},<)$ the element $0$ is defined by a formula $\phi(x)$ that states there is no number less than $0$, and every integer $n>0$ is definable by a formula $\phi(x)$ that states there are exactly n elements less than x (from a wikipedia article that helped me understand the concept) so, it's more like trying to "fit in" the element of the universe within the structure using the proposed relation, in this case, $<$. Formula meaning first-order formula containing quantifiers.

Comment: it would still be cool to hear your idea though @saulspatz, maybe there is a possibility to create a formula with it, based on the divisibility...

Comment: I assume there are formulas $\phi_k,\ k=2,4,7$ such that $\phi_k(x)\iff x\in k\mathbb{Z}$  Then I would show that for all $8$ sets of truth values of $\phi_k, \ k=2,4,7$ there is an  $x\in11\mathbb{Z}$ that gives those values and an element  $y\notin11\mathbb{Z}$ that gives those values.  As I say, I don't know model theory, so I'm not certain this is sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, there aren't $8$ possible values, since $\phi_4(x)\implies \phi_2(x)$

Comment: hmmmm I see what you mean, but I think that's the issue, how to construct a formula using only the relation $<$. Perhaps through the cardinality of sets? Just some kind of entities that could be compared against each other with that order relation... I'm confused...

Comment: There's a couple typos in the question. Most importantly, "$x=11\mathbb{Z}$" should be "$x\in 11\mathbb{Z}$:" $11\mathbb{Z}$ is a **subset**, not an **element**, of your structure. On a more minor note, "$\mathbb{N}$" should be "$\mathbb{Z}$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that **any definable subset of a structure $\mathcal{A}$ must be preserved by all automorphisms**: if $D\subseteq\mathcal{A}$ is definable and $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{A}$ we must have $D=\{\alpha(d):d\in D\}$. If you haven't seen this before, it's a good exercise (use induction on complexity). This gives us a powerful tool for proving undefinability: simply exhibit an automorphism which doesn't preserve the set *(or function or relation for that matter)* in question!

So first let's consider the problem of understanding $Aut(\mathcal{M})$:

> What are the automorphisms of $\mathcal{M}$?

As a hint, note that the automorphisms of the simpler structure $(\mathbb{Z};<)$ are just the **shift maps** $\alpha_z:x\mapsto x+z$ for $z\in\mathbb{Z}$. So you just need to figure out **which shifts preserve the additional structure of $\mathcal{M}$**.

*HINT: think about least common multiples ...*

> The automorphisms of $\mathcal{M}$ are exactly the maps of the form $$\alpha_z: x\mapsto x+28z$$ for $z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Now can you find an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ which does not preserve $11\mathbb{Z}$?

> For example, the map $x\mapsto x+28$ sends $11\in11\mathbb{Z}$ to $39\not\in11\mathbb{Z}$.

---

It's worth noting that this "automorphism trick" is **not always applicable**. For example, the structure $(\mathbb{Z};0,<)$ has no automorphisms at all but of course "most" of its subsets are not definable (it has uncountably many subsets but only countably many definable subsets). In general we have to use more complicated techniques - key terms include "quantifier elimination" (and its weaker-but-more-common cousin "model completeness") and "Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games."

On the other hand, this "automorphism trick" is **not limited to** first-order logic specifically. There are other logics of interest (e.g. second-order logic, infinitary logic(s), and a whole slew of others) and it works for them too: "isomorphism-invariance" is generally considered one of the criteria something has to satisfy in order to be a logic.

So the "automorphism trick" is simultaneously rather limited *and* surprisingly broad!

Comment: Thank you so much Noah!! If only our professor would tell us about some of these tricks... so, I've understood the least common multiples construction, but, did you perhaps mean $39 \not\in \mathbb{11Z}$ in the end? Since, well, I reckon it is in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{11Z}$.

Comment: @LinShao Whoops, yes I did - fixed!

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch again :)

Comment: @LinShao Glad to help!